# How to add a null row in sql server2008r2

Tags: sql, null

I want to add a row that serves like a space between data in sql...

```
ID num |    owner   |  time in  |  time out  |

<-- space  /row

255414 |     anne   |  7:45     |   6:00     |

<-- space / row

141455 |     jane   |  8:00     |   5:30     |
```

Comment: Why you need null row?

Comment: I think, you can add null row in Select query while presenting data. that would be ideal, rather than saving it like this.

Comment: If you have a different requirement to space out different rows of data a cleaner solution would be to do this at the UI level instead of at sql.

Comment: `insert into table(ID num,owner,time in,time out)
values(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)`

Comment: Don't do it. Database tables are for data, not for whitespace. And anyway... when you will SELECT from this table the blank rows will never end up where you want them, either because you used an ORDER BY, a WHERE, or just because the ENGINE decided to use an INDEX to resolve the query. Even in Excel (which is where this comes from IMHO), leaving blank rows between data is a very bad habit (as it breaks most formulas and ordering operations).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this, you must not set any integrity constraint in your schema definition and declare all the fields as varchar. Then you can insert a null row like this.

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES ('', '', '', '');
```

This will create a seperator in your database.

If you are using integer in your columns, you must pass all values as NULL while inserting into database. Somthing like this:-

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (NULL, '', NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add or Pass null values using insert query. But if you have Identity column it will be incremented. Or Just add a row or separate column which will flag a end of group of rows.